# How do I use an existing element as content for every new tabview item?

Tags: winui-3, windows-app-sdk

Hi I am using C# WinUI 3 WinAppSDK for my app.
I have a tab view with add tabs option and i also have a home page panel which is collapsed at general state.
Now whenever the user adds a new tab, I want the same home page to appear as its content instead of programmatically adding each element in the tabview item.
When I set this:
newItem.Content = homepagegrid;

I get this error:
System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

Comment: Does it need to be the same instance? or just the same type of page.

Comment: If you need the same **home page** instance for each new ``TabViewItem``, it might be very tricky since it belongs to a ``TabViewItem``.

Comment: Creating instances of **home page** but binding them to the same ViewModel might be a way to do this.

Comment: I agree to realize the public use of the panel through ViewModel, and you can also copy the content of the home page panel into a new Page. `newTab.Content = frame;
 frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1))`